# Consume REST API from a PL (PostgreSQL 11)

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on a project in which I must build a PL that should consume a REST service (return in JSON). Looking at the PostgreSQL documentation, I didn't find functions equivalent to Oracle's UTL_HTTP.

I found some tutorials in which the DBA built the PL using PL / Python to make HTTP requests.

Does PostgreSQL not have native support for HTTP requests?

Comment: I don't think it does, but the [`pgsql-http` extension](https://github.com/pramsey/pgsql-http) might be what you're looking for. It's a wrapper around libcurl.

Comment: I do not have permissions to perform program installations on the environment's operating system. :'(